# more efficient solution for QTableWidget write

Tags: python, performance, qtablewidget, pytables

I am reading a PyTable, with 1320000rows x 16cols

The idea is to read the table and to write its content into a QTableWidget.

The way I am doing it makes the GUI collapse.

I would like a clue about how to do it in an efficient way.

Here it is my code:

```
#The PyTable is already opened and the reference to the desired table acquired

self.ui.tableWidget.setRowCount(tab.nrows)
self.ui.tableWidget.setColumnCount(len(tab.colnames))
self.ui.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(tab.colnames)
res = []

#Read the PyTable row by row and store the result
for x in tab.where('col1 > -1'):
    res.append(x[:])

#Try to write the QTableWidget row by row
for i, row in enumerate(res):
    for j, col in enumerate(row):
        item = QTableWidgetItem(str(col))
        self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(i, j, item)   

#NOTE 1: with a PyTable with 1000rows X 16cols rows aprox it works perfect
#NOTE 2: with the huge PyTable with 1320000rows x 16cols, it does not work
```

Comment: With a huge table like that... you DON'T want to put the entire table in the widget. You want to implement the scrolling yourself, so you are only writing into the widget what's actually visible on the screen.

Comment: Thanks Corley, I was already thinking about that, but I don't have any idea about how to make this scrolling. Any suggestion or any place where I could read about it?. Thanks!