# QTableWidget Efficiency

Tags: python, csv, pyqt5

I am using my code below to read and render a large CSV file (2002 rows with a lot of data). Here is the code I have so far, and it works. However, not quite as quickly as I'd like to. On my mac, the Application becomes "Unresponsive" and I get stuck on a rainbow wheel for a good minute before it loads the data. Is there anything I can do to make this bit of code more efficient?

```
class OpenCSV(QtWidgets.QTableWidget): 
    def __init__(self, r, c):
        super().__init__(r, c)
        self.check_change = True
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.cellChanged.connect(self.c_current)
        self.show()

    def c_current(self):
        if self.check_change:
            row = self.currentRow()                    
            row = self.rowCount()
            value = self.emails(row,col)
            value = value.text()
            print("The email in the box is: ", value)

    def open_sheet(self):        
        self.check_change = False
        path = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,'Open File',os.getenv('Home'), 'CSV(*.csv)')
        if path [0] != '':
            with open(path[0],'rU') as csv_file:
                self.setRowCount(0)
                self.setColumnCount(1)
                load_file = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
                for emails in load_file:
                    row = self.rowCount()                    
                    emails = re.findall(r'[\w_]+@[\w_]+\.[\w_]+', open(path[0]).read())                    
                    self.insertRow(row)
                    for row, stuff in enumerate(emails):
                        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(stuff)
                        self.setItem(row, 1, item)
        self.check_change = True
```

Comment: You can share your .csv file, I would also recommend you get the number of rows and columns in advance, change it in each iteration time consuming.

Comment: Also I recommend not printing during charging, disconnect the cellChanged signal but it is necessary.

Comment: There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22173626/more-efficient-solution-for-qtablewidget-write?rq=1) where in the comments it is suggested that you implement scrolling for loading the data to the `QTableWidget`, instead of loading all at once for large data sets.

Comment: A custom model with a `QTableView` is the fastest way to populate a table (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39088300/984421) for a demo).